# How can I reduce Image file Size in Python

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Django Project where in my Form I have a Python method that I want to first check whether the uploaded image is jpg, jpeg, gif or png, and then check if the uploaded image is more than 14kb and reduce it to be less than or equal to 14kb.
The issue is that the first check (allowed file formats) is done correctly but the second check is not working correctly instead, the image is uploaded without the file size reduced.
Below is my code:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
full_name = forms.CharField(label = 'Full Name:', max_length=36, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Your Full Name'}))
email = forms.CharField(label = 'Email Address:', max_length=36, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter a Valid Email Address'}))
phone_number = forms.CharField(label = 'Phone Number:', max_length=11, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Your 11 Digits Phone Number.'}))
state = forms.CharField(label = 'State:', max_length=12, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter State  of Residence Name Only.'}))
address = forms.CharField(label = 'Residential Address:', max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Street Name with Number (where applicable) and Town Name only.'}))
class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['full_name', 'phone_number', 'email', 'country', 'state', 'town', 'address', 'image']

def validate_image(image):
    if not mimetypes.guess_type(image.name)[0] in ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]:
        return "Invalid file format. Only JPG, PNG, and GIF images are allowed."

    image = Image.open(image)
    width, height = image.size
    if width > height:
        image = image.rotate(90)

    # Check the file size.
    image_bytes = io.BytesIO()
    image.save(image_bytes, format='JPEG')
    file_size = image_bytes.tell()
    if file_size > 14000:
        # Calculate the resizing dimensions to reduce the file size while maintaining the aspect ratio.
        aspect_ratio = width / height
        new_width = int(140 * aspect_ratio)
        new_height = int(140 / aspect_ratio)
        image = image.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    return image
```